Power BI complex DAX filtering
My main table contains a percentage, a date and an id. I need calculate how many months an id has been below 80 percent.
I believe I want to create a new table, which filters my main table based on the percentage, and remove all non-consecutive months for an id (up until last month).
From then on I can calculate the months between last month, and the oldest row for each id.
How would I go about filtering non-consecutive registrations for each id?
EDIT: It's pretty hard to explain, so let me add some more comments. The data is timeregistration from employee's on different projects. The percentage is calculated using external and internal hours. So I would like to find the employees with 80% or more internal hours.
In the example, I have already filtered using the percentage.
ID 1 has 80% internal hours in March and February. So the months since last external project should result in 2.
ID 2 only has 80% internal hours in March. So the months since last external project should result in 1.
ID 3 has 80% internal hours in March, February and December. But since January is missing, as they had 80% of external hours, the months since last external project should result in 2.


Can you supply sample data and expected results

@davidebacci I've tried explaining it further, but I find it difficult to explain. I hope it helps though!
